# Best way to generate bit.ly or twitpic style ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, uniqueidentifier, short-url

For a personal project I'm working on, I'd like to generate ids for objects on my website in the same style as sites like bit.ly and twitpic.  Sending users to `example.com/4gwv9k` would let me get the item with id `9gwv9k`.  Is this simply a question of auto-incrementing on a base-36 scheme or is there some underlying, non-incrementing magic going on?

This is all being done in Rails, so any gem support would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on I did it in Sinatra.

https://github.com/chrisledet/shorty_url

Answer (score 3):

You may use autoincrement integer translated to 62 based number (26 small letters + 26 cap letters + 10 digits)

Comment: Some suggestions on how to do this would be phenomenal.